# Adding space between values of a json array in JSP

Tags: javascript, html, json, jsp

I am having some names as output in a JSP like:

```
<div class="someClass">
        ${myData.personsList}
</div>
```

Here, `myData` is a `JSON` object with `personsList` as a `JSONArray`.

The output I get is:

```
Henry Foo,Michael Bar,Johnny Lost,Vicky Found
```

How do I add space between the names so that the output is like:

```
Henry Foo, Michael Bar, Johnny Lost, Vicky Found
```

I tried `${myData.personsList.join(', ')}` and `${myData.personsList}.join(', ')` but both are literally printing `.join(', ')` and not interpreting like I am assuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried [Javascript Array Join()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) like this. it works fine.

```js
function demo(){
    var myData = {
        "personList" : ["Henry Foo","Michael Bar","Johnny Lost","Vicky Found"]
    }
    
    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = myData.personList.join(", ");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="demo()">click</button>
<div id="data">
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Regex and replace**

```js
var jsonData = 'Henry Foo,Michael Bar,Johnny Lost,Vicky Found';

var newData = jsonData.replace(/,/g, ", ");

console.log(jsonData);
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this(not tested though ):

```
<c:forEach var="name" varStatus="status" items="${myData.personsList}"> 
     ${name} 
     ${not status.last ? ‘’ : ‘, ’}
 </c:forEach>
```